# How do I know that $1 parameter is stdout on assembly?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls, cpu-registers

So I was reading [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux#Examples) example on the Wiki Books about x86 Assembly/Interfacing with Linux which has the following code.

```
.data
msg: .ascii "Hello World\n"

.text
.global _start
_start:
    movl $4, %eax   # use the `write` [interrupt-flavor] system call
    movl $1, %ebx   # write to stdout
    movl $msg, %ecx # use string "Hello World"
    movl $12, %edx  # write 12 characters
    int $0x80       # make system call
    
    movl $1, %eax   # use the `_exit` [interrupt-flavor] system call
    movl $0, %ebx   # error code 0
    int $0x80       # make system call
```

What I want to know is where can I find documentation or information about what each register does when calling a specific system call.

For example how do I know that `movl $1, %ebx` writes to stdout or that `movl $12, %edx` sets the number of characters to write to the buffer.

Comment: 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr.  That's unix (system calls); C, assembly, or otherwise.

Comment: Let me search for you: https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=x86